# How to get ExpandEnvironmentVariables to return custom variables?

Tags: c#

I have added a custom environment variable and I'm unable to get it to return in the ExpandEnvironmentVariables.

**These 2 calls work fine:**

```
string s = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

// s = "D:\Temp2"

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\Temp1");
```

// path = "C:\Windows\Temp1"

**However, this call returns the same input string:**

```
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%TEST%\Temp1");

// path = "%TEST%\\Temp1"
```

I expect to get D:\Temp2\Temp1

What am I missing to correctly get the custom EnvironmentVariable in this last call?
[image: Envionmental Variables]

Comment: Are you setting the variable in code? If so can you edit your question to include that code?

Comment: Most obvious reason is that you added this variable to the System environment without restarting either VS or your program.  Be 100% that the changes are effective by logging out and logging back in again.

Comment: To set the System Variables i simply use the OS interface undet system properties.  I am only retrieving the variable in code. GetEnvironmentVariable works, but ExpandEnvironmentVariables does not...

Comment: It looks like `GetEnvironmentVariable` gets its values from the registry, whereas `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` uses a Win32 call. That's probably why the difference in behaviour, but I've no idea how to make them behave the same.

Comment: Try to run program without debugger (without VS), or just restart Visual Studio after you created that TEST variable. Then it should work (for the reasons I don't completely understand to be honest).

Comment: @HansPassant if you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.  I did a machine restart, but I'm sure a VS restart would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hans and Evk were correct in their comments.  Since no one wanted to add an answer I'll close this question out.

For whatever reason ExpandEnvironmentVariables will not get any keys which were added after an application started.  I also tested this with a running Windows Service.  It was only after I restarted the service that new keys were found and populated.

This behavior is not documented in the Microsoft Documentation.